# UNIX Script that check each minute who logs in and out?

Tags: shell, unix

can some one please tell me, how can I checks each minute and reports on who logs in and who logs out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting point, take a look here:

- http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/39579-users-who-loged-within-5-minutes.html

Using `who -s` gives you the log in times of the users currently logged in. The link above uses a 5-minute threshold to filter the list, but you can change it to 1-minute.

You can either make a script that does the above and then sleeps for 60 seconds in a while loop or maybe use `cron` to set up this to run every minute (though I would prefer a script for short periods like that).

You would miss the users who logged in and out between the two script runs, though.

I guess you would need more then a script if you need a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "last" command to get a list of recent login history.  Do you want to see the login/logouts since you last ran the script, or literally in the last minute?

Comment: Literally in the last minute. Thanks for the quick reply.